# What's wrong with Johnson SU fit using moment=find (SuppDists)

Tags: r, distributions, qq-plot

I have a vector of returns `r` that have skew and kurtosis. I want to fit a Johnson SU distribution to this data.

Using the code below:

```
plot(qJohnson(ppoints(r),JohnsonFit(r, moment='find')),
sort(r), xlim=range(-.2,.2), ylim=range(-.2,.2)); abline(0,1)
```

This results in the QQPlot below. Clearly there is something wrong with the estimation. When I use the `moment='quant'` I get a better fit (most of the points are over the x=y line.

Am I using the JohnsonFit function right?

[image: JSU Fit]

Comment: The data is in https://gist.github.com/anonymous/62dc0c08f16470614c94